# How to let the program exit with a 0 after printf finished?

Tags: assembly, arm, return, printf

This little program just prints the 2 argv written in shell.

```
.global main

main:
    ldr r2, [r1,#8]
    ldr r1, [r1,#4]
    ldr r0, =message_format
    bl  printf
    mov r0, #0

message_format:
    .asciz "argv: %s %s\n"
```

I want it to exit with a 0 code so I put #0 inside r0, but:

```
root@kali-pi:~/Desktop/arm_test# ./arggggg 1 2
argv: 1 2
Segmentation fault
root@kali-pi:~/Desktop/arm_test# echo $?
139
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: maybe call exit() with a 0 ... I dont know the ARM ABI so i am not sure how to do that, but presumably return from main isn't exactly the same as a return from a function...

Comment: You have to call an exit function or put a return instruction to return from the `main` function. Your example has neither, so the execution just "falls through" into whatever follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How could I fix this?

Assembly programs do not have an "end":

Because the memory of your computer is typically longer than the assembly program, there is some data following the assembly program. And because the CPU does not destinguish between data and code, it will interpret the bytes following the assembly program as code.

Example:

Let's say you have Thumb code and the RAM after your program contains the bytes 1, 2, 3, and 4. Then the CPU will interpret your program as:

```
ldr r2, [r1,#8]
ldr r1, [r1,#4]
ldr r0, =message_format
bl  printf
mov r0, #0
lsls r1, r0, #8
lsls r3, r0, #16
...
```

The CPU will run until some instruction is found that cases an error.

You have two possibilities that the other users already wrote in a comment:

**1) Explicitly use the exit() function or similar**

You may call the `exit()` function to exit from your program immediately.

This is done like calling the `printf()` function.

**2) Return from the main() function**

You may use `bx lr` to return from the `main()` function.

Unfortunately, the `printf()` function will overwrite the value of `lr`, so a simple `bx lr` would cause an endless loop.

You'll have to save the `lr` register before calling `printf()` and to restore it later on.

Example:

```
push {lr}
ldr r2, [r1,#8]
ldr r1, [r1,#4]
ldr r0, =message_format
bl  printf
mov r0, #0
pop {lr}
bx lr
```

If you are compiling Thumb code, `pop {lr}` won't work. Use `pop {r1}` and `bx r1` instead.

If you are sure that both the `main()` function and the function that called the `main()` function are of the same code type (ARM or Thumb), you can also use only one instruction at the end: `pop {pc}`.

This is the case when working on a Cortex M CPU that only supports Thumb code or when working on an old ARM CPU that did not support Thumb.

Comment: Thanks for answer. My professor does exactly the same thing as you do, but with only one difference. `push {ip, lr}` instead of `push {lr}` and `pop {ip, lr}` instead of `pop {lr}`. Can you tell me why my professor also writes `ip` and not only `lr`?

Comment: @Mnkisd: `push {lr}` would misalign the stack.  IIRC, the ARM calling convention requires 8-byte stack alignment, or at least that's what GCC maintains by default for performance reasons.  e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/nfaW17 shows what GCC does.