# Assembly Code Segmentation Fault in Raspberry pi 4 (scanf)

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm, raspberry-pi4

I am coding an assembly program (consideration to a C program) in raspberry pi 4. I was doing up my assembly code but I received this error after the user has put the first input.

[image: segmentation fault]

I am still not so sure what's the problem but I am guessing it might be the scanf problem. I am going to put a snippet of the code here:

```
.data

.balign 4
msg1: .asciz "Enter a positive integer number length (m): \n"

.balign 4
scanfPattern: .asciz "%d"

.balign 4
length1Read: .word 0

.text
.global main
.extern printf
.extern scanf

main:
  LDR R0, msg1Add
  BL printf
  LDR R0, scanfAdd
  LDR R1, length1Add
  BL scanf
  LDR R0, length1Add
  LDR R0, [R0]

 msg1Add : .word msg1
 scanfAdd : .word scanfPattern
 length1Add : .word length1Read
```

Hopefully this is sufficient enough to describe my problem because I don't want to throw out my entire code over here. FYI: yes i did BX LR to end the program in the end, but error still persist.

Comment: Use your debugger to pinpoint the fault. PS: you can do `ldr r0, =length1Read` to get the address with the help of your assembler so you do not need to set up the literal pool by hand :) Also, you did save and restore `LR` properly, right? While we do not want your entire code, we like to have a [mcve] which is a trimmed down but runnable version of your code that still produces the error.

Comment: Without a [mcve], closing as a duplicate of [How to let the program exit with a 0 after printf finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63362632) which shows how to exit properly.  Since your program did wait for input instead of crashing before that, scanf was probably called correctly.  We don't know where you put `bx lr`, but your code certainly isn't saving/restoring its incoming return address so at best you'd get an infinite loop.  Or if you put it after the `.word` data, then those would execute as instructions.

Comment: Also, you don't need to run `as` separately; GCC will do that for you before linking, if you give it a `.s`.  So `gcc -o q2  q2.s`